# Saving the Filter Data in Ext.util.Cookies to save the previous State

Tags: javascript, extjs, cookies, extjs3

There is a problem of handling the state of a Editor Grid. I am using

```
Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow ({ refilterOnStoreUpdate : true}).
```

I have succeeded to save the state through Ext.util.cookies.set.

And when i refresh the page the state is getting set to the previous state by retrieving the data from Ext.util.cookies.get.

But I am unable to set the values of the filter field values after page refresh.

The code on beforeLoad event of the Store :

```
 searchConditions = Ext.encode(filterDetails);
 searchValues = Ext.encode(columnDetails);
 alert(' searchConditions ----> ' + Ext.encode(columnDetails));
 Ext.util.Cookies.clear('filterData');
 Ext.util.Cookies.clear('columnMap');
```

On page refresh i am doing this :

```
filterDetails = (Ext.decode(Ext.util.Cookies.get('filterData')));   
columnDetails = (Ext.decode(Ext.util.Cookies.get('columnMap')));
```

Is there any setFieldValue or anything to set the field value in FilterRow.js ?

Comment: In what format do you store the filter? Why are you unable to set the filter ? What is the problem ?

Comment: As i am using FilterRow.js. I am able to store the Filter in the cookies.
But i am unable to show the Filter field values which were entered earlier by user before page refresh.
i am getting the values from the filter as follows :  searchConditions ----> {"wsName":"Modify","orderNo":"280"}

Comment: Can't you explain better or at least show your code ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: Can you please have a look at the code update . In case anything else needed to understand the same. Please let me know.

Comment: What version are you using ? In the doc of 4.2.2 I cannot find Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow, but the doc at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature states *A filters property is added to the GridPanel using this feature*. There are also methods `addFilter` and `addFilters`. Maybe this helps ?

Comment: I am using ext js 3.4

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Hopefully i Solved this one too. Whether its a good approach or not may be you can tell me as you worked with EXT 4.2, As i have explained earlier that i am storing the filter values in previous state. So i used jquery to set the values of my ext rendered input box like this.                                       $( '#mygrid-filter-2 input' ).val(searchValues.appName);
 $( '#mygrid-filter-3 input' ).val(searchValues.wsName);

Comment: I can't really tell you if it is a good approach. You're collegues will tell you when they will maintain the app in the future. IMO, I would not mix ExtJs and JQuery, I would decide for one of them and do everything with the same framework. It is cleaner to stick on as few frameworks (external components in general) as possible. Two is one too much, when both do the same job, like in this case, where you can achieve the same with ExtJs.